# Marginalization in Graph SLAM

Tags: slam, computer-vision, sensor-fusion

I have several questions about the process of marginalization in SLAM algorithms:

0 - What are the mathematic intuition behind marginalization process

1 -  I know marginalization of states or points is related with removing nodes from the graph and keeping the information they have, how this information is kept? I mean, how the information of the marginalized states are passed to the remaining state?

2 - Why in bundle adjustment, the points are set marginalized? (example of ORBSLAM implementation)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. As it says in [ask] *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you had same question as me.

I wrote my own answer [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/15464/why-do-we-need-a-marginalization-in-bundle-adjustment) which will be the answer to your question 0, 1, 2.