# How does marginalization work in fixed lag smoothing?

Tags: slam, visual-odometry, ba

I have read in SLAM papers talk about marginalization. I am confused about how this process works, why you do it and how it differs from global smoothing.

In particular if you're interested in Windowed Smoothing I don't understand how marginalization is different than full bundle adjustment? If marginalization carries the full information from the prior states, then why do global bundle adjustment?

Comment: From my understanding, you remove older nodes, but introduce additional constraints in order to retain most of the information the nodes contained. Briefly speaking, this will make optimization faster in exchange for a little accuracy. Here's a more detailled answer https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/15482/33402

Comment: Hi @PhilipZ. - I rejected your [suggested edit](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17771) as it seems to alter the meaning. I believe that the OP means `If marginalization carries the full information from the prior states, then why [bother] do[ing] global bundle adjustment [as well]?` and not the opposite which your edit would have implied. However, we both could be wrong - only the OP would actually know..! :-)